# CUDA version with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to install tensorflow with GPU on my Windows 10 laptop. I have downloaded cuda (version 9 because it is the latest one) and had issues because dll `cudart64_80.dll` didnt exist. I do have `cudart64_90.dll` which leads me to believe that tensorflow only works with cuda 8.

Im wondering if I should unisntall CUDA 9 and then install CUDA 8 or if I can have both versions installed?

Comment: Speaking from experience tensorflow has issues with CUDA 8 and cuDNN 7, let alone CUDA 9. I tried building tensorflow 1.2/1.3 with CUDA 8 and cuDNN 6/7, build failed on all combinations. Finally, went back to tensorflow 1.1, CUDA 8 and cuDNN 5.1.

Comment: cuDNN is another problem, the framework site (https://developer.nvidia.com/deep-learning-frameworks) point you to download v7 even though it says v5.1 is supported as you said....do you know where to download V5.1..cant find it

Comment: cuDNN 5.1, 6.0, 7.0 are available on Nvidia's official webpage. But please note that cuDNN 5.1 only works for tensorflow < v1.2.

Comment: I removed the CUDA tag from this question because it has nothing to do with CUDA programming -- it is about Tensorflow and which versions of CUDA it may or may not be compatible with. Please don't re-add it

Comment: ok, was trying to get the attention of people with "CUDA experience"